# NDK build error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I built a NDK Android project in Android Studio,I got this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:android:assembleDebug]
executing buildNative
executing cleanNative
:android:buildNative
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
make.exe: Entering directory `F:/Android_Studio_Project/HelloToone/android'
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libgs.so <= jni/
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libgs.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libgs.so
F:/ADT/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip:./libs/armeabi-v7a/libgs.so: File format not recognized
make.exe: *** [libs/armeabi-v7a/libgs.so] Error 1
make.exe: *** Deleting file `libs/armeabi-v7a/libgs.so'
make.exe: Leaving directory `F:/Android_Studio_Project/HelloToone/android'
:android:buildNative FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:buildNative'.
> Process 'command 'F:\ADT\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

I downloaded `libgs.so` file from http://ghostscript.com/~robin/libgs.so and put it into `jni` folder.
How to slove this error? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/  for ndk howto

Comment: I have seen this site, but I still have this error.

Comment: With default ndk config , its trying to rebuild your lib from source.